# how do i stop a square movement in python so that it could move the opposite way?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
from time import *
tk=Tk()
WIDTH=1350
HEIGHT=700
canvas=Canvas(tk,width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
color="blue"
touchingground=False
xspeed=0
yspeed=0
def jump():
    global touchingground,yspeed,xspeed
    if touchingground==True:
        yspeed=-1.2
tk.bind("<w>",lambda x: jump())
def goright():
    global touchingground,yspeed,xspeed
    if xspeed<=7:
        xspeed=xspeed+1
def goleft():
    global touchingground,yspeed,xspeed
    if xspeed>=-7:
        xspeed=xspeed-1
tk.bind("<d>",lambda x: goright())
tk.bind("<a>",lambda x: goleft())
player=canvas.create_rectangle(200,0,210,10,fill="red")
xspeed=0
yspeed=0
thebox1=canvas.create_rectangle(200,650,520,700,fill="black")
while True:
    canvas.move(player,xspeed,yspeed)
    tk.update()
    sleep(0.01)
    pos=canvas.coords(player)
    if xspeed>0:
        xspeed=round(xspeed-0.2)
    elif xspeed<0:
        xspeed=round(xspeed+0.2)
    if pos[3]>=HEIGHT:
        touchingground=True
        canvas.move(player,0,-0.1)
        yspeed=0
    else:
        touchingground=False
        yspeed=yspeed+0.01
    if pos[0]>=1350:
        canvas.move(player,-1350,0)
    if pos[2]<=0:
        canvas.move(player,1350,0)
    if canvas.find_overlapping(200,639,520,700)==(1,2):
        xspeed=-xspeed
    if canvas.find_overlapping(200,649,520,700)==(1,2):
        touchingground=True
        canvas.move(player,0,-0.1)
        yspeed=0
tk.mainloop()
```

i made this code and i don't know how to make the wall stop moving after it hits a cube, but start moving again when button `a` or `d` pressed.

Comment: You already have code to do something when it touches the ground. Why not use that same method to detect when it touches an 'invisible' object at either edge of the canvas? Or just check to see if the objects X position is greater than the width or less than 0?

Comment: BTW using a while loop isn't a great idea. Consider calling an `update` function periodically using the `.after` method. `tk.after(100, update)`. Update function would be the contents of your while loop minus the `sleep` and `update` function calls.